# Xamarin C#: Trying to center button horizontally causes it to go off screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout, center

Basically I'm trying to place a button using percentage of screen. Percentage size and percentage location. The button is placed at **X: 0.5f and Y: 0.0f** meaning it should be centered at the top of the screen.

```
Button button = new Button(Application.Context);
int height = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * heightPercent);
int width = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * widthPercent);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
{
    LeftMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * xPercent - (width / 2)),
    TopMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * yPercent),
    BottomMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * yPercent) + height,
    RightMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * xPercent + (width / 2)),
    Width = width,
    Height = height
};


button.Tag = buttonID;
button.LayoutParameters = params1;
```

The code above causes the button to go off screen even though that makes no sense. If I change the margins to this;

```
LeftMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * xPercent),
TopMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * yPercent),
BottomMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * yPercent) + height,
RightMargin = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * xPercent) + width,
```

The button will appear on screen but be slightly offset to the right. I'm trying to move it to the left by half of it's size but I have no idea why the layout freaks out. Any hints?

How the button gets added to the layout:

```
int MaxWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
int MaxHeight = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;

base.OnCreate(bundle);
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

layout.SetMinimumHeight(MaxHeight);
layout.SetMinimumWidth(MaxWidth);

<BUTTON GETS CREATED HERE>

layout.AddView(button);
SetContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Where did you add the `Button` to your layout? What is your `Button`'s parent view? Please post your code.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I added the code used to add the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin C#: Trying to center button horizontally causes it to go off screen

You could use [LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.LayoutRules/) to implement this feature, for example :

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
Button button = new Button(this);
button.Text = "Center Button";

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
parametros.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
layout.AddView(button, parametros);

SetContentView(layout);
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLyYZ.png).